# How can I recurse through a dictionary and dynamically update values so that they can be later referenced?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion, yaml

I am experimenting with writing a configuration variable engine that accepts a YAML file (containing AWS config variables) as an input and converts to JSON so that it can be uploaded to an HTTP k/v API (such as Consul). A feature on which I am stumped would allow the developer to "include" key sets (identified with an underscore, which are omitted in the final payload) in subsequent keys. An exemplar is as follows:

```
# Region
us-east-1:
  # Any key preceded by an underscore (_) is considered a "tag group" and will not be uploaded to Consul KV unless explicitly included.
  _taggroup1:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
    key3: value3
  _taggroup2:
    key4: value1
    key5: value2
    key6: value3

  dev:
    _include: us-east-1/_taggroup1
  qa:
    _include:
      - us-east-1/_taggroup1
      - us-east-1/_taggroup2
    key6: baz
  prod:
    _include:
      - us-east-1/_taggroup1
      - us-east-1/_taggroup2

us-west-1:
  _taggroup1:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
    key3: value3
  _taggroup2:
    key4: value1
    key5: value2
    key6: value3

  dev:
    _include:
      - us-west-1/_taggroup1
  qa:
    _include:
      - us-west-1/_taggroup1
      - us-west-1/_taggroup2
    key2: foo
  prod:
    _include:
      - us-west-1/_taggroup1
      - us-west-1/_taggroup2
    key4: foo
    key5: bar
    key1: undef

  us-west-1a:
    qa:
      _include: us-west-1/qa
    prod:
      _include: us-west-1/prod

  us-west-1b:
    _include: us-west-1/us-west-1a
```

As you can see, I am trying to structure a config file that allows developers to group variables and subsquently include/override them if they wish.

The code I have written for this experiment so far is essentially your standard recursion function with additions specific to this application:

```
# parse_input is a separate function that converts a YAML stream into
# an OrderedDict
original_dict = parse_input(stream1)

def print_dict(input_dict):

    new_dict = collections.OrderedDict()

    for key, value in input_dict.iteritems():
        if key.startswith('_'):
            if key == '_include':
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    for item in value:
                        x = dpath.util.get(original_dict, item)
                        for k, v in x.iteritems():
                            new_dict[k] = v
                else:
                    x = dpath.util.get(original_dict, value)
                    for k, v in x.iteritems():
                        new_dict[k] = v
            else:
                continue
            continue
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            new_dict[key] = print_dict(value)
        else:
            new_dict[key] = value
    return new_dict
```

The output so far that I have achieved is as such:

```
{
    "us-east-1": {
        "dev": {
            "key1": "value1", 
            "key2": "value2", 
            "key3": "value3"
        }, 
        "qa": {
            "key1": "value1", 
            "key2": "value2", 
            "key3": "value3", 
            "key4": "value1", 
            "key5": "value2", 
            "key6": "baz"
        }, 
        "prod": {
            "key1": "value1", 
            "key2": "value2", 
            "key3": "value3", 
            "key4": "value1", 
            "key5": "value2", 
            "key6": "value3"
        }
    }, 
    "us-west-1": {
        "dev": {
            "key1": "value1", 
            "key2": "value2", 
            "key3": "value3"
        }, 
        "qa": {
            "key1": "value1", 
            "key2": "foo", 
            "key3": "value3", 
            "key4": "value1", 
            "key5": "value2", 
            "key6": "value3"
        }, 
        "prod": {
            "key1": "undef", 
            "key2": "value2", 
            "key3": "value3", 
            "key4": "foo", 
            "key5": "bar", 
            "key6": "value3"
        }, 
        "us-west-1a": {
            "qa": {
                "_include": [
                    "us-west-1/_taggroup1", 
                    "us-west-1/_taggroup2"
                ], 
                "key2": "foo"
            }, 
            "prod": {
                "_include": [
                    "us-west-1/_taggroup1", 
                    "us-west-1/_taggroup2"
                ], 
                "key4": "foo", 
                "key5": "bar", 
                "key1": "undef"
            }
        }, 
        "us-west-1b": {
            "qa": {
                "_include": "us-west-1/qa"
            }, 
            "prod": {
                "_include": "us-west-1/prod"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I appear to be halfway there. My problem is that in my initial experimentation I was getting favorable results by referencing the `original_dict` variable in the function when referencing an include set (using `dpath` to return the keys).  This quickly turns into a problem as the function recurses deeper (ie, AZ-specific variables in this case), as I do not know how to dynamically update keys in the original dict, or otherwise keep track of changes, so the function will inject a key set with `_include` keys and fail to re-evaluate them.

How do I eliminate depending on referencing the original dictionary, and rather dynamically track changes so that `_include` keys are properly evaluated deeper in the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code fixes the issue you were facing.  Key change is to recurse to `print_dict` with the result from `dpath`.  I also collapsed some redundant code.

**Code:**

```
import yaml
import collections
import json
import dpath

with open('data.yml', 'rb') as f:
    original_dict = yaml.load(f)

def print_dict(input_dict):

    new_dict = collections.OrderedDict()

    for key, value in input_dict.iteritems():
        if key.startswith('_'):
            if key == '_include':
                if not isinstance(value, list):
                    value = [value]
                for item in value:
                    x = print_dict(dpath.util.get(original_dict, item))
                    for k, v in x.iteritems():
                        new_dict[k] = v
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            new_dict[key] = print_dict(value)
        else:
            new_dict[key] = value
    return new_dict

print(json.dumps(print_dict(original_dict), indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "us-east-1": {
    "qa": {
      "key3": "value3", 
      "key2": "value2", 
      "key1": "value1", 
      "key6": "baz", 
      "key5": "value2", 
      "key4": "value1"
    }, 
    "prod": {
      "key3": "value3", 
      "key2": "value2", 
      "key1": "value1", 
      "key6": "value3", 
      "key5": "value2", 
      "key4": "value1"
    }, 
    "dev": {
      "key3": "value3", 
      "key2": "value2", 
      "key1": "value1"
    }
  }, 
  "us-west-1": {
    "qa": {
      "key2": "value2", 
      "key3": "value3", 
      "key1": "value1", 
      "key6": "value3", 
      "key5": "value2", 
      "key4": "value1"
    }, 
    "us-west-1b": {
      "qa": {
        "key2": "value2", 
        "key3": "value3", 
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key6": "value3", 
        "key5": "value2", 
        "key4": "value1"
      }, 
      "prod": {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key3": "value3", 
        "key2": "value2", 
        "key6": "value3", 
        "key5": "bar", 
        "key4": "foo"
      }
    }, 
    "prod": {
      "key1": "value1", 
      "key3": "value3", 
      "key2": "value2", 
      "key6": "value3", 
      "key5": "bar", 
      "key4": "foo"
    }, 
    "us-west-1a": {
      "qa": {
        "key2": "value2", 
        "key3": "value3", 
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key6": "value3", 
        "key5": "value2", 
        "key4": "value1"
      }, 
      "prod": {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key3": "value3", 
        "key2": "value2", 
        "key6": "value3", 
        "key5": "bar", 
        "key4": "foo"
      }
    }, 
    "dev": {
      "key3": "value3", 
      "key2": "value2", 
      "key1": "value1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This appears to work!  Thank you, I had (obviously) not tried that yet! :)